# Change ghci version on stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have stack installed on my computer for haskell:

```
Developers-MacBook-Pro:~ developer$ stack ghci
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /private/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/ghci2170/ghci-script
Prelude>
```

As you can see version is still 8.0.1. Then I upgraded the stack as follow:

```
Developers-MacBook-Pro:~ developer$ stack upgrade
Current Stack version: 1.3.2, available download version: 1.4.0
Newer version detected, downloading
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64-static
Querying for archive location for platform: osx-x86_64
Downloading from: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v1.4.0/stack-1.4.0-osx-x86_64.tar.gz
Download complete, testing executable
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
New stack executable available at /Users/developer/.local/bin/stack
```

After I start `stack ghci` again and I've got still version 8.0.1, what am I doing wrong?

The image shows, that `ghci` version 8.0.2 has successfully installed:
[image]

The path is `/Users/developer/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/`

**Update**
In the path `/Users/developer/.stack/`, there is a folder called `global-project` and I change the yaml as follow:

[image]

Now stack ghci run on version 8.0.2:

```
Developers-MBP:~ developer$ stack ghci
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /private/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/ghci526/ghci-script
```

Comment: To switch to the latest LTS snapshot (which currently uses GHC-8.0.2), you can run `stack config set resolver lts`.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#what-version-of-ghc-is-used-when-i-run-something-like-stack-ghci,

> The version of GHC, as well as which packages can be installed, are specified by the *resolver*.

So, to change the version of GHC used when executing `stack ghci` *outside* stack projects, do:

1. Find an existing resolver in `~/.stack/build-plan`, e.g. `lts-10.4`, or download a new resolver you need;
2. Execute `stack config set resolver lts-10.4`. Yes it updates `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`.

As thus, `stack ghci` outside stack projects will use GHC 8.2.2, which is the GHC version specified by resolver `lts-10.4` (This relationship can be found at https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.4, or in file `~/.stack/build-plan/lts-10.4.yaml` which says `ghc-version: '8.2.2'`).

Answer (score 3):

`stack` is a build tool that coordinates building projects with different versions of GHC and sets of dependencies. So you can upgrade `stack` independently of ghc.

I'm not quite sure what the expected behavior of `stack ghci` is when it's run outside of a project directory. Presumably you con configure the default version of `ghc` to use in that case in your `~/.stack/config.yaml`. See: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/

You should also be able to do:

```
$ stack ghci --with-ghc ghc-7.10.3
```

But usually the version of ghc is determined by the stackage snapshot you've configured for your project, for instance if you have a `stack.yaml` with:

```
resolver: lts-3.3
```

...you will be using ghc-7.10.3

Comment: When I  want to start `stack ghci` without a project I want to use version 8.0.2 not 8.0.1, how can I switch the version?